# Automatically files are adding in the Source control section in VS CODE?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

So I am working on a project and in there I have to use the  --disable-web-security chrome version ... automatically files are adding in my Source control section in just the few span of minutes over a thousand files are adding .

[image]

I am using UBUNTU and this is a react project and Github for version control

Comment: are you putting your project in `/var/tmp`

Comment: you don't use `github` for version control, you use `git` for SCM

Answer (score 0):

This view lists all files in your project folder. So the question arises why you would use var/tmp as your project folder in the first place.

Move your code and the repository somewhere else to avoid being overwhelmed with files from other applications.